# implement hierarchical data structure in DDD

Tags: domain-driven-design, hierarchical-data

If you want to implement a hierarchical model in DDD, will your referrals be to parents only or will you also refer to a list of children?

Consider a simple ticketing system in which we are supposed to have a maximum of two answers per ticket. In fact, the answer goes to only two levels.

- Post: Aggregate Root

  Comment: Entity

Given the above condition, I think I should also refer to the list of comments because it has limitations. On the other hand, for Aggregate Root itself, it will have only two response levels when fetched, which returns, and this has no effect on performance.

What is your opinion and what factors do you think should be considered in this design? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you correctly, I don't think it matters if the children reference its parent or if the parent reference its children for it to be a hierarchical model with a specific AR. But if you need the children to be an ordered list I would go with first alternative with the parent referencing its children. But if all you need is an unordered collection I would use the other variant. I this specific case with comments I guess each Comment would have a Posted:DateTime, and could then be sorted on this property instead of being ordered. If it instead would have been for instance a list of steps to take to complete a task, then the ordering would have been more important of course.